# Android HW for development: On external storage when the external SD card is not supported?

Tags: android, hardware, software-design, nexus-7

**Context:** I am considering to buy the *reference* tablet Nexus 7 for testing the application during development. I cannot tell you now what kind of applications exactly. They will probably be just portable clients for bigger IT applications (database apps, web-services based communication). I am fairly good in C++, but I do not have the Java hands-on experience. Just studying the official Android web pages.

From what I have learned so far, Android supports *internal storage* and *external storage* -- each with specific features. In that sense...

**The question:** Does Nexus 7 implement the *external storage* somehow? Is the lack of the external SD (for Nexus 7) related to the *external storage* as a term at all? Can the lack of external SD be a limitation when designing/developing some sorts of applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Does Nexus 7 implement the external storage somehow? Is the lack of the external SD (for Nexus 7) 
related to the external storage as a term at all? Can the lack of external SD be a limitation 
when designing/developing some sorts of applications?
```

As **Nexus 7** doesn't have a External Memory Storage Card but its internally manage it. When you call `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` then its return to path `/mnt/sdcard/` which is in-built their as a External Storage.

So there is no issue for developing application.

Comment: Happy Coding..! We are here for help..! :-)